# Salesforce Docusign logging error

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to connect docusign with salesforce. In app in SF I logged in into docusing but in loggint into salesforce sandbox I got error:

> Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element enableAdminLoginAsAnyUser

[image]

Comment: Hi did you figure this out, I was OK in a production environment but unable to do this in my pre-prod envs.